# Generating Swagger definition file (JSON or YAML) from springboot REST service

Tags: swagger, aws-api-gateway

I have implemented AWS API Gateway, which has many API methods. Currently, I have created a swagger definition file (JSON format) and imported this file AWS API Gateway though the "import" option available.  I am also developing REST API services in springboot that gets called from the AWS API Gateway. The REST API Service has 20 API methods and I want to have these 20 API Methods in API Gateway. I do not want to manually maintain a Swagger definition file, containing the definition for these 20 API methods. I would like to know if I can generate Swagger definition file from SpringBoot API.

I know that Swagger can create HTML documentation from the REST API but I did not find any tool that could convert this HTML to a Swagger definition file. I also know that Swagger inspector can generate the definition file, but I have to manually call each service endpoints manually to create the definition file.

Comment: did u find answer